# My function wont Plot for an array of variables

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a graph for the Voltage/resistance Relationship of a Quarter-bridge Wheatstone bridge, so that i can compare it to my actual values. The code is as follows:

```
Vin = 3.3; %Voltage input
DR = 0.19*10^3:0.01*10^3:0.30*10^3; % Change in resistance due to stretch sensor
R0 = 1.3*10^3; % Initial resistance of other 3 resistors
R= R0+DR;

VQB = (DR/((4*R0)+(2*DR)))*Vin;  % General Quarter Bridge Equation

vout = 6.8*VQB; % Amplified Output voltage

plot(R,vout); hold on
```

Im not sure why but i get no data in the plot, i have used the function just like this before where i have an array of incrementing data being pumped into an equation to generate an output. But this time it only gives a single data point. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a point also before ^ where you raise to a power

```
DR = 0.19*10.^3:0.01*10.^3:0.30*10.^3; % Change in resistance due to stretch sensor
R0 = 1.3*10.^3; % Initial resistance of other 3 resistors

VQB = (DR./((4*R0)+(2*DR)))*Vin;
```

Should work now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Put a point just after DR in VQB to compute the VQB for all components of DR:

```
Vin = 3.3; %Voltage input

DR = 0.19*10^3:0.01*10^3:0.30*10^3; % Change in resistance due to stretch sensor
R0 = 1.3*10^3; % Initial resistance of other 3 resistors
R= R0+DR;

VQB = (DR./((4*R0)+(2*DR)))*Vin;  % General Quarter Bridge Equation

vout = 6.8*VQB; % Amplified Output voltage
figure(1), hold on;
plot(R,vout); 
xlabel('R')
ylabel('vout')
```